# Is there a Bloomberg field for the first trading date after an event?

Tags: bloomberg

For example, if a company reports earnings today after the close (6/24), the earnings date would be 6/24 but the field I'm looking for would be 6/25. If they reported tomorrow before the open, both fields would be 6/25. If they reported this Friday 6/26 after the close, this field would be Monday 6/29.

BB obviously has this since they show day 1 price reaction (on ERN for example) but can't tell me how to get it as a single field.

(This would be for US stocks, mainly earnings and offerings.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HELP HELP can probably help you on this. But as far as I know there isn't a field that has this information. You can probably calculate it.

You could retrieve the content of the `EARN_ANN_DT_TIME_HIST_WITH_EPS` field - it contains dates and times of earning releases.

Alternatively you could use the `EXPECTED_REPORT_TIME` which has a `EQY_FUND_RELATIVE_PERIOD` override if you need past data.

You can then compare the times with the trading hours for the stock.